# React useEffect hook does not call after recoil atom updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-effect, recoiljs

I'm using recoiljs as my state manager for my react project, and one of my components doesn't call it's useEffect when a recoil atom changes from another file. Here is my main component that reads from an atom.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../css/MeadDeadline.css'
import {getNearestDate} from '../chromeAPI/retrieveDeadlineJSON'

import DeadlineList from '../atoms/deadlinelist'
import {useRecoilValue} from 'recoil'

export default function MainDeadline() {
    // get the date and the stuff from chrome storage
    const [school, setSchool] = useState("");
    const [date, setDate] = useState("");
    let [deadlinelist, setDeadlineList] = useRecoilValue(DeadlineList);

    useEffect(() => {
        const nearest = getNearestDate(deadlinelist);
        const len = nearest.length;

        if (len === 0){
            setSchool("No schools registered");
            setDate("");

        } else if (len === 1){
            setSchool(nearest[0].school);
            setDate(nearest[0].date);
            
        } else {
            // we need to render a lot of stuff
            console.log("error");
        }

    }, [deadlinelist]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="MainDeadline">
                <div className='school'>{school}</div>
                <div classNmae='date'>{date}</div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is my atom file

```js
import {atom} from 'recoil'

const DeadlineList = atom({
    key: "deadlinelist",
    default: []
}); 
export default DeadlineList;
```

and here is the form that I'm submitting in

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../css/InputForm.css'
import checkList from '../utils/checkList'
import checkDate from '../utils/checkDate'
import {storeNewDeadline} from '../chromeAPI/storeNewDeadline'

import {useRecoilState} from 'recoil'
import DeadlineList from '../atoms/deadlinelist'
import SchoolList from '../atoms/schoollist'

export default function InputForm () {
    const [inputschool, setInputSchool] = useState('');
    const [inputdate, setInputDate] = useState('');
    const [invalidschool, setInvalidSchool] = useState(false);
    const [invaliddate, setInvalidDate] = useState(false);
    const [badschool, setBadSchool] = useState('');
    const [baddate, setBadDate] = useState('');

    const [schoollist, setSchoolList] = useRecoilState(SchoolList);
    const [deadlinelist, setDeadlineList] = useRecoilState(DeadlineList);

    const validateForm = () => {
        // check to make sure its not in the list
        const valschool = checkList(schoollist, inputschool);
        if (!valschool){
            setInvalidSchool(true);
            setBadSchool(inputschool);
        } else {
            setInvalidSchool(false);
            setBadSchool("");
        }
        // check to make sure the date hasnt been reached yet
        const valdate = checkDate(inputdate);
        if (!valdate){ // add MSIN1DAY becauase the day value is 0 indexed so conflicts with Date() and date input
            setInvalidDate(true);
            setBadDate(inputdate);
        }
        else {
            setInvalidDate(false);
            setBadDate("");
        }

        return !invalidschool && !invaliddate; // want both to be valid
    }

    const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // validate the form
        if (validateForm()){
            storeNewDeadline(inputschool, inputdate);

            // change schoollist state
            let slist = schoollist;
            slist.push(inputschool);
            setSchoolList(slist);

            // change deadlinelist state
            let dlist = deadlinelist;
            dlist.push({
                "school": inputschool,
                "date": inputdate
            });
            setDeadlineList(dlist);

            console.log(deadlinelist, schoollist);
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (event, fieldname) => {
        switch (fieldname) {
            case "inputschool":
                setInputSchool(event.target.value);
                break;
            
            case "inputdate":
                setInputDate(event.target.value);
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className='InputForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Enter New School</h3>

            <div id='inputname' className='Inputer'>
                <p>School Name</p>
                <input 
                    type='text'
                    onChange={e => {handleChange(e, 'inputschool')}}
                    value={inputschool}
                    required 
                />
                {invalidschool ? <p>{badschool} is already registered</p> : null}
            </div>

            <div id='inputdate' className='Inputer'>
                <p>Deadline Date</p>
                <input
                    type='date'
                    onChange={e => {handleChange(e, 'inputdate')}}
                    value={inputdate}
                    required
                />
                {invaliddate ? <p>{baddate} is invalid</p> : null}
            </div>

            <div id='inputsubmit' className='Inputer'>
                <p>Submit</p>
                <input type='submit' required></input>
            </div>
            
        </form>
    )
}
```

If you want to just see file for file the github is [here](https://github.com/JeffreyHuang06/deadlinemanager-extension/tree/recoilstate)
The main component is src/components/MainDeadline.jsx , src/atoms/deadlinelist , src/components/InputForm.jsx

My main problem is when the user inputs something in the form, it's supposed to update the state, but the main component doesn't update.

Please tell me if I can improve my code in any way this is my first react project.

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is that you are directly modifying the recoil state with this: `let dlist = deadlinglines; dlist.push({/*...*/});` `dlist` is a reference to the actual state. You should instead clone the existing list. `let dlist = [...deadlinelist, {school: school, date: date}]`

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with arrays in state hooks, you need to clone the array as you do the set function.

Also, instead of this:
let [deadlinelist, setDeadlineList] = useRecoilValue(DeadlineList);

I would do this:
const [deadlinelist, setDeadlineList] = useRecoilState(DeadlineList);

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to close it after stumbling my way to the solution but thanks for explaining *why* useRecoilState rather than useRecoilValue works